# How to properly display backticks in verbatim environment?

Tags: verbatim, code

I am preparing a beamer presentation where I need to display some markdown code involving backticks. Specifically, I want to show backticks in the `verbatim` environment. However, LaTeX renders them as open quotation marks.

**How can I ensure backticks in the verbatim environment display as backticks?**

Here's a minimal example:

```
\begin{verbatim}
Example: `2 + 2`
\end{verbatim}
```

An ideal solution would not require me to change the code itself.

Comment: I don't know if it is an option for you but using `LuaLaTeX`/`XeLaTeX` with `fontspec` generate the right characters.

Comment: Wow.  User asks latex to: "relay these characters verbatim", and then latex transforms all delimiters to a 32-bit ISO-8859-1 Latin glyph set and replacing single quotes with variable angle diacritics.  I'm starting to think I know why Latex is now a 6.5GB 90 minute install.  Someone at the helm is having a laugh throwing sand in those gears.  Verbatim must be interpreted in bizarro world which means: "Change everything to be something else, at random".

Answer (score 20):

You can also use the relative new package [`upquote`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/upquote), which is explicitly created for that task – together with the change for single quote marks, compare [How to make a real apostrophe or single-quote in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63345/9237).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{upquote}
\begin{document}
\begin{verbatim}
Example: `2 + 2`
\end{verbatim}
\end{document}
```

Without `upquote`:
[image: Example without "upquote"]

With `upquote`:
[image: Example with "upquote"]

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to do this with a variation of the code found under a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1662037/how-to-write-programming-code-containing-the-character-in-latex).

In your case, add the following to your preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\let\@sverbatim\@verbatim
\def\@verbatim{\@sverbatim \verbatimwithtick}
{\catcode``=13 \gdef\verbatimwithtick{\chardef`=18 }} 
\makeatother
```

In the verbatim environment this sets the definition of ` to correspond to the 18th character in the font table which is a back tick. Normally it corresponds to an opening quote.

Answer (score 1):

With eTeX, @jpallen doesn't need auxiliary commands:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
{\catcode`\`=13
\xdef\@verbatim{\unexpanded\expandafter{\@verbatim}\chardef\noexpand`=18 }
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{verbatim}
Example: `2 + 2`
\end{verbatim}
\end{document}
```

Comment: ``{\catcode`\`=13 \g@addto@macro\@verbatim{\chardef`=18 }}`` seems less complicated. :)

Comment: Eh, complicated? I can't see the complication!