# Problem with symbols/accents

Tags: symbols

Please consider the following MWE

```
\documentclass[xcolor=pdftex,t,11pt]{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{An example}
\begin{itemize}
\item Testing the hypothesis that $\widehat{\beta}_{i}$ is equal to all values between $1$ and $3$ could be boring. \medskip
\item Augmenting the null hypothesis by $0.2$ points each time implies that we need to repeat our command 11 times.\medskip
\item To shorten the procedure, we can use the command {\tt{forvalues}}.\medskip
\item {\tt{forvalues}} (and also {\tt{foreach}}) lets us to create loops.\medskip
\item Let us write the following in the command window:\medskip
\begin{center}
{\tt{forvalues i=1(0.2)3.2\,\ \{}}\\
{\tt{test ertsp=`i'}}\\
{\tt{\}}}
\end{center}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

After typesetting, I get:

[image]

Instead, I should obtain exactly how I wrote in latex, i.e. `i'.

How can I get it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

I've added `upquote` package for the ticks in `\verb` and `[fragile]` for the `\verb` in the `frame` environment.

```
\documentclass[xcolor=pdftex,t,11pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{upquote}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{An example}
\begin{itemize}
\item Testing the hypothesis that $\widehat{\beta}_{i}$ is equal to all values between $1$ and $3$ could be boring. \medskip
\item Augmenting the null hypothesis by $0.2$ points each time implies that we need to repeat our command 11 times.\medskip
\item To shorten the procedure, we can use the command {\tt{forvalues}}.\medskip
\item {\tt{forvalues}} (and also {\tt{foreach}}) lets us to create loops.\medskip
\item Let us write the following in the command window:\medskip
\begin{center}\ttfamily
forvalues i=1(0.2)3.2\,\ \{\\
test ertsp=\verb|`|i\verb|'|\\
\}
\end{center}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Credits to [How to properly display backticks in verbatim environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63353/how-to-properly-display-backticks-in-verbatim-environment).

Comment: @Dario You're welcome, thank you for accepting my answer!