# \texttt converts apostrophe to Unicode quotation mark

Tags: unicode, characters, typewriter, code

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make a real apostrophe or single-quote in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63345/how-to-make-a-real-apostrophe-or-single-quote-in-latex)

I'm building a Python Regex cheat sheet using Latex, which has the following line:

```
\texttt{re.match('a\textbackslash sb', 'a b')
```

However, when the line is copied from the PDF document, the apostrophe (`'`) is converted to [`Unicode Character 'RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK' (U+2019)`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2019/index.htm) (`’`):

```
re.match(’a\sb’, ’a b’)
```

This text is not recognizable by the Python interpreter.

Is there a LaTex tag for code that preserves the original characters?

Comment: I wouldn't have expected that, what tex engine are you using. If it's pdftex try adding `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`

Answer (score 6):

With pdflatex use `\textquotesingle` or `\verb` together with the package `upquote`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{upquote}
\begin{document}
\texttt{re.match('a\textbackslash sb', 'a b')}

\texttt{re.match(\textquotesingle a\textbackslash sb\textquotesingle, \textquotesingle a b\textquotesingle)}

\verb+re.match('a\sb', 'a b')+
\end{document}
```

But you should be aware that copy code lines from a pdf can be problematic: e.g. spaces and identation can easily change.

Comment: I don't seem to have pdflatex in texShop (Mac OSX), and it does not work with `LuaLatex` nor `XeLaTeX`.

Comment: You certainly have pdflatex. But I forgot a brace in the code (now corrected). With lualatex/xelatex + `\usepackage{fontspec}` I can't reproduce your problem. You should make a complete example.