# Display real apostrophe in parts of a document

Tags: punctuation

The question [How to make a real apostrophe or single-quote in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63345/how-to-make-a-real-apostrophe-or-single-quote-in-latex) is my question too, but the answer points to a package `upquote` that affects the entire document. I need to display an apostrophe (U+0027) only a couple of times within the document. Otherwise I would like the general conversion to quote to take place.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec, xunicode, xltxtra}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping = tex-text}

\begin{document}
\noindent I would like an apostrophe to appear in the word ap'ple (U+0027), but a right quotation mark (U+2019) when I quote the word `orange'.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: So you actually want in some places to _not have_ the typographically right apostrophe/right quotation mark (U+2019)  but the vertical typewriter apostrophe `'` (U+0027, the one that you get by hitting the `'` key, which is the one that appears in the input)? How should LaTeX distinct between the two types of input?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: Presumably by having two distinct inputs ...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Solution 1: Markup for quotations

One simple way to do this would be to *not* use the `Mapping=text-tex` (which, BTW has been replaced with the `Ligatures=TeX` option) and use the `csquotes` package to manage your quoting.  Here's an example:

```
% !TEX TS-program = XeLaTeX
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}

\begin{document}
\noindent I would like an apostrophe to appear in the word ap'ple (U+0027), but a
 right proper quotations marks (U+2019) when I quote a word with double quotes:
 \enquote{orange} or single quotes: \enquote*{orange} or double quotes using the
 "Active Quotes" function of the package.
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

### Solution 2: Define an apostrophe font and markup

Another way would be to load your font twice, once using the `Ligatures=TeX` and the other without, and then define markup for the apostrophe.

```
% !TEX TS-program = XeLaTeX
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Linux Libertine O}
\newfontfamily\quotefont{Linux Libertine O}
\newcommand{\apostrophe}{{\quotefont'}} % or just use {\quotefont text}


\begin{document}
\noindent I would like an apostrophe to appear in the word ap\apostrophe ple
(U+0027), or {\quotefont ap'ple} but a right proper quotations marks (U+2019) when I
quote a word with double quotes: ``orange'' or single quotes: `orange'.
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

In this solution, the markup for the apostrophe isn't actually necessary, since any text that is grouped with `{\quotefont ... }` will use the single quote as typed.

Comment: Both of these solutions seem to be perfect. In my specific scenario, however, it turns out that your pointing out the ``Ligatures=TeX`` is all I need, because in the cases I need the apostrophe to appear as an apostrophe, the font is not my main font, so I can just not include ``Ligatures=TeX`` as an option in my ``\newfontfamily\coolfont\{Name of my cool font}`` call.

Comment: Another, and perhaps the easiest, solution is given in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103076/turn-off-fontspecs-option-ligatures-tex-inside-document

Comment: @Sverre The Mapping solution only works for XeLaTeX and can't be extended to LuaLaTeX, though.

Answer (score 7):

Another method (I got the idea from reading *2 Font commands* in the XeTeX reference (`texdoc xetexref`)):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{libertine}

\newcommand{\apostrophe}{\XeTeXglyph\XeTeXcharglyph"0027\relax} 

\begin{document}
\noindent I would like an apostrophe to appear in the word ap\apostrophe ple
(U+0027) but a right proper quotations marks (U+2019) when I
quote a word with double quotes: ``orange'' or single quotes: `orange'.
\end{document}
```

Here is the result (also tested ok with other fonts):

[image: right quote]