# Turn off fontspec's option Ligatures=TeX inside document

Tags: xetex, fontspec

This question is in some ways similar to [Display real apostrophe in parts of a document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99757/display-real-apostrophe-in-parts-of-a-document), but I am now asking about the possibility of performing a specific operation.

I can turn *on* the typical TeX text mapping of quotes etc. by using `fontspec`'s option `Ligatures=TeX`. Whereas `fontspec` allows many of the `Ligatures` options to be deactivated (cf. `fontspec`'s documentation, table 2), I can't find any way of deactivating an already activated `Ligatures=TeX`, since there is no option of the sort `Ligatures=NoTeX`. Does this mean it is not possible to momentarily turn off `Ligatures=TeX` inside a document?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
    \setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Linux Libertine O}
\begin{document}
CA'GT -- {\addfontfeatures{Ligatures=Common}CA'GT}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can turn off the mapping by using an empty mapping:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
    \setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Linux Libertine O}
\begin{document}
CA'GT -- {\addfontfeatures{Mapping=}CA'GT}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This solution only works with XeLaTeX and not LuaLaTeX though.

Answer (score 8):

The `Ligatures=TeX` doesn't apply a font feature, but rather adds a "mapping"; this is part of the log describing the main font:

```
. fontspec info: "defining-font"
.
. Font family 'LinuxLibertineO(0)' created for font 'Linux Libertine O' with
. options [Ligatures=TeX].
.
. This font family consists of the following shapes:
.
. * 'normal' with NFSS spec.:
. <->"Linux Libertine O/ICU:script=latn;language=DFLT;mapping=tex-text;"
.
. * 'small caps' with NFSS spec.:
. <->"Linux Libertine O/ICU:script=latn;language=DFLT;mapping=tex-text;+smcp;"
.
. * 'bold' with NFSS spec.:
. <->"Linux Libertine O/B/ICU:script=latn;language=DFLT;mapping=tex-text;"
. [...omitted similar lines...]
```

While this feature could be turned off, I'd prefer defining a different font family without the option:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Linux Libertine O}
\newfontfamily{\mainnolig}{Linux Libertine O}

\begin{document}

CA'GT -- {\mainnolig CA'GT}

{\itshape CA'GT -- {\mainnolig CA'GT}}

\end{document}
```

As the example shows, font attributes are preserved, so the effect is the same as what you wanted to get with `\addfontfeatures`. The chosen name is just to provide the example, use whatever you prefer.

[image]

Comment: You can turn off the mapping by using an empty mapping:
`{\addfontfeatures{Mapping=}CA'GT --}`.

Comment: @egreg: Yes, that's exactly what I do as well (as suggested by Alan Munn in http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/99776/9077), but I was curious if there was a way of "turning off" the ``TeX`` mapping.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: You're right. Do you wanna provide an answer, or should I just add it myself?

Comment: The choice of name `\mainnolig` could be a bit confusing to some readers, as the font family will still have the `Common` ligatures (mostly f-ligatures) enabled. Maybe it's better to call the font family `\mainnotexlig`? Just a thought.

Comment: @Mico: I agree. My font family is called ``NoTeX`` :)