# what is the apostrophe symbol?

Tags: typography

The following code

```
\documentclass[varwidth, margin = 1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
apostrophe '\\
apostrophe  as a Unicode character 2032 `^^^^2032\\ %requires xelatex                                                                                                                                         
apostrophe in math mode $'$
\end{document}
```

gives the result

[image]
As one can see the apostrophe in free form, as a Unicode character `2032` and in math mode appears in different ways.

How can I produce an apostrophe similar to the one in math mode in a free text without using the awkward step of going into math mode?

Comment: Do you mean something like `\newcommand{\apostrophe}{{\quotefont'}}`?  [Display real apostrophe in parts of a document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/99776/124842)

Comment: It's a  `prime` (Unicode U+2032) but most text fonts for pdftex do not have both a curly and straight right quote

Comment: `\newcommand\textprime{\ensuremath{'}}`

Comment: Routine in LuaLaTeX or XeTeX, where you can directly use Unicode with Open Type fonts, thanks to `fontspec`. Many Open Type fonts, including some available via TeX, have the prime symbol. Then, as David noted, `^^^^2032` places the character without need for math mode. Or you can simply paste it in from a character map.

Comment: How does one enter a Unicode character?

Comment: @Viesturs Unicode entry only works if your document uses utf-8 encoding. I specifically think of LuaLaTeX and XeTeX (I do not know how it works if it works, in pdflatex). To enter a character at Unicode hex PQRS (where PQRS is 0 to lowercase f) type `^^^^PQRS. Alternatively, find the character in a Unicode character map, copy and paste into your document.

Comment: I inserted the Unicode option. Latex gives a `prime` symbol different than given in https://unicode-table.com/en/#2032

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use `pdflatex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\newcommand{\textprime}{\ensuremath{'}}
\newunicodechar{′}{\textprime}

\begin{document}

Arnol′d

$f'(x)$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Don't use `′` in math mode, unless it's for a single prime.

For XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\setmainfont{Libertinus Serif}

\newcommand{\safeprime}{\ensuremath{'}}
\newunicodechar{′}{%
  \iffontchar\font`′′\else\safeprime\fi
}

\begin{document}

Arnol′d

\end{document}
```

The usage of `\newunicodechar` is a safety measure in case the font doesn't have the glyph corresponding to U+2032 PRIME.

[image]