# Why can't I type a normal quotation marks in TexShop?

Tags: punctuation, texshop

When I type the quotation by ``'' in editor and then output a PDF file, these symbols cannot display. For example, if I want to display

> "Hi",

the PDF will only show

> Hi.

I know typing `` and `''` is the correct way to show quotation marks. But, my problem is, when I type two apostrophes, the TexShop will automatically "correct" my types into `"`.

Comment: You should not use `"` in latex markup: use `\`\`` for open quote and `''` (that is two single quotes) for close quote

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thx, David. But my problem is, when I type two apostrophes, the TexShop will automatically "correct" my types into `"`.

Comment: try to disable `Key Bindings` in preferences?

Comment: @datcn that's _odd_ for an editor designed for Tex use, to automatically break your input. Sorry I can't help then, I have never used texshop

Comment: Just use package `csquotes` and write instead of quotation marks `\enquote{Hi}` to get the result you want ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally noticed that this problem was caused by the chosen encoding format of TexShop editor. I change it back to UTF-8 and then the problem disappeared.

Thanks a lot for all your answers and inspirations.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that your problem is that Texshop convert the quotes not to straight " but to curly “citation marks”, cfr. [this similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/110789/9632).

Since you have not provided a MWE, I just have to guess, but those characters are eight bits and require proper support in PdfLateX to show up in the PDF (have a look at the logs to see error messages).

Try to add the following lines to the preamble of your document:

```
\usepackage{lmodern}  % or your other font package
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

I anticipate that the quotation marks now show up in the PDF.

If not, please provide an MWE.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer, @Sveinung . However, I even cannot type " before generating the PDF file. Luckily, this problem has been solved by choose another encoding format of the editor.

Comment: @datcn This is the reason for why you are asked to provide an MWE. If you had done that, we could probably had eliminated my suggestion from the start.