LyX Converts Apostrophe from ' to ’ After Compiling – How to Fix?
Whenever I compile a document in LyX, the apostrophe symbol (') gets automatically converted to a curly apostrophe (’). How can I prevent this from happening?
I only need this for one specific spot where it's different; I don't mind the rest. Can I set this universally or only for certain places?

Welcome to the TeX.SE. community. Can you see this link: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110789/texshop-keeps-converting-apostrophes-into-curly-ones ? Is it the same issue?

\textquotesingle? Generally, conversion to curly is what you want. Is there any particular reason you want to buck the convention? Or are you actually trying to do something different and really need different markup?

@Sebastiano I'm not sure because I don't use LyX, but the linked question is about the editor changing the source, whereas this one is about compilation 'changing' it. Though if that's the correct interpretation, it isn't really changing it. ' just is the markup for a curly closing single quotation mark.

Related: punctuation - How can I input normal quotes in LyX? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange and xetex - How to get straight quotation marks? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange

I needed the function for code which I showed in my document. This: \usepackage{upquote} helped me :) It changed the symvol at the code areas to the wished one, thank you all!
