# Display ' apostrophe

Tags: punctuation

Is there a small package free way of implementing something like this in pdflatex and LaTeX?

I wish for the outcome of

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
    `It's a nice day!'
\end{document}
```

To be

> ʻIt's a nice day!ʼ

I know that due to there being a single apostrophe inside the quote can mess up stuff, so I'm more then happy to use a function or macro, like `\apos`, to insert it.

I know that the apostrophe I want has the Unicode value of 39, so is in the standard ASCII implementation. "U+0027 ' apostrophe (HTML: `&#39;` `&apos;`) typewriter apostrophe."

Comment: In addition to the duplicate, see also http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/63348/9077

Comment: The "duplicate" question and its answers are specifically about unicode and fontspec, which isn't the case here. I voted to re-open

Answer (score 85, accepted):

It's a rather unusual convention, but if you want it then:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\begin{document}
    `It\textquotesingle s a nice day!'
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is that actually the proper character to use for an apostrophe? So should I always be writing `it\textquotesingle s` if I want to be technically correct?

Comment: @DavidZ no it's horrible:-) The normal usage is to use `'` but the OP asked for a straight quote and if that's what he wants, this is the latex markup to get it.

Comment: Apostrophe, open-single-quote, close-single-quote, are all different characters, but ascii over loaded apostrophe onto close-single-quote (I think). I Think that unicode has added separate characters. I don't know about latex.

Comment: If it's unusual, is it a "convention?"

Answer (score 40):

David's answer is preferable, but here's another option if you don't want to load any package to take care of it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
`It\textsc{\char13}s a nice day!'
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect! It took reading through so many pages of COMPLICATED answers to find this simple solution.  Now I can define a new command for the rare times I want this:

`\newcommand*\vtick{\textsc{\char13}}`

and then just place `\vtick` in my document where I want it to appear.

Comment: This seems to font dependent. If I use revtex with `\usepackage{times}` it does not work.

Comment: @TravisBemrose - Note that the method depends on both the font encoding -- it works for the basic `OT1` encoding, but not for `T1` -- and the font family; as shown above, it works for `Computer Modern`, but it may not work with any other font families. This is probably why Sverre wrote, "David's answer is preferable." :-)