# Package listings and Perl here documents with apostrophes

Tags: listings, perl

I sometimes write ordinary English prose in my here documents in a Perl usage sub, for example

```
 --[no]alias    [don't] use the alias list in the ini file (default noalias)
```

The problem is the a single apostrophe seems to disturb the listings package. A short example:

```
\documentclass[article]{memoir}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{language=Perl,stringstyle=\slshape}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
my $commentA =   "Please, don't do this";
my $commentB =   "But do this";

print <<HERE;
Please, don't do this
But do this
HERE

my $commentC =   "Please, don't do this";
my $commentD =   "But do this";
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

This results (with MiKTEX/TeXstudio) in

[image: Result]

The apostrophe in commentA is ignored, while the one in the here document seems to be interpreted as an opening quote.

I have tried to escape the here terminator, but to no avail. Any suggestions (short of avoiding apostrophes in here documents)?

Comment: I think [How to make a real apostrophe or single-quote in LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63345) is related.

Comment: @Johannes_B I think the question is about the strange formatting one gets in e.g. commentC with the bold "do" after a HERE statement containing an apostrophe, rather than the shape of the apostrophe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a `morestring` for these here statements.  With the `s` option you can have a pair of delimiters, though this is not quite clear in the documentation:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[article]{memoir}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{language=Perl,stringstyle=\slshape}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[morestring={[s]{<<HERE;}{HERE}}]
my $commentA =   "Please, don't do this";
my $commentB =   "But do this";

print <<HERE;
Please, don't do this
But do this
HERE

my $commentC =   "Please, don't do this";
my $commentD =   "But do this";
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I didn't even notice the bold **do**. Glad there is a solution.

Comment: I have two minor worries. I usually use meaningful here terminators, which requires several morestrings, and in calls to subs with several arguments like
    mysub (<<HERE, $arg1, $arg2);
    …
    HERE
the first line is formatted as a string -- unless, of course, I use
    [morestring={[s]{HERE, $arg1, $arg2);}{HERE}]
and then I lose a possible keywordstyle for keywords in the arguments.

Comment: @HenrikSnog Agreed - the solution is going to work best if you keep the keyword and HERE name spaces disjoint.  In particular, your HERE name should not be something that could be the argument to a binary shift operator, or you should use a space after `<<` in such a case.