# Single quotation typed in overleaf Latex editor is different from pdf

Tags: symbols

I checked the following link:
[apostrophe](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63345/how-to-make-a-real-apostrophe-or-single-quote-in-latex)
I typed the following:
because the 'Tools'

Kindly see the attached image.

Somebody, please guide me on how to 'what you see is what you get'

Zulfi.[image]

Comment: For the opening quote you need a backtick `\``: `\`Tools'`.

Comment: The link you point to is trying to get an output that more closely matches the input than TeX would otherwise use.  If you're just wanting quotes, then follow campa's suggestion, which what TeX is expecting you to do.